# Unable to create a 777 file on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

How can I create a file (not directory) with execution permissions using umask?
I know files use 666 permissions and directories 777 but I want to create files with 766, for example.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to create files that everyone on the system can write to? That's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chmod to change the file permissions.

```
chmod 777 some-file
```

Or set the umask

```
umask 000
```

Comment: Setting the `umask` to `000` is a bad idea. It will cause *all* files you create to have `666` permissions (read, write, and execute by everyone).

Comment: @KeithThompson 777 is also a bad idea but that was the question.

Comment: The OP asked how to use `umask` for something for which `umask` is not the best approach. That's worth mentioning in your answer, even if the OP didn't directly ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly using `umask`, you cannot do this.  Unless you are specifically creating an executable file with, say, `gcc`, the default permissions will be `666 minus umask`.  You must use `chmod` to add the executable bit to a standard file.

Comment: "666 minus umask" is not correct - if the umask was set to 1, that would give a result of 665. The correct invocation is "666 and not umask", or as a C expression, for better readability - `0666 & ~umask`...